# How to list all the elements in a list in Appium

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I am looking for `Appium` code where it will list all the web elements present in a class, For instance i want to try something as

```
List<WebElement> listOfElements;
listOfElements = (WebElement) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'view.test')]"));

System.out.println(listOfElements);
```

The class contains at least 8 elements. Is there a way to list all the 8 elements in `appium`

The above code is not working , I don't see any `appium` library for importing list too. So, is there a way to get entire list of identifiers belonging to a class in `appium`.

Comment: Please post your screenshot with UI Automator elements view & possible appium log too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the elements in a list and then iterate through that list to print the elements.
You can do it like:

```
List<WebElement> listOfElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'view.test')]"));
for(WebElement element: listOfElements){
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

And if you want to print the element text(if it is present), then you can do it like:

```
List<WebElement> listOfElements = Constant.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'view.test')]"));
for(WebElement element: listOfElements){
    System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```